# Is there any GIT command to find list of branches and its creators with its last modified date

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I am looking for output in texfile in a formatted way so that I can automate to mail the branch owners directly. Any one kindly help to get the list of branch names user(creator) wise along with last modified date

Comment: branch owner means user who created the branch

Comment: Yes, git doesn't store this kind of metadata about branches. You can maybe find author of the first divergent commit, but that's about it.

Comment: okay even thats fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using [for-each-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref)

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(authorname) %09 %(refname)'
```

Comment: This will fetch author of last commit in the ref. Should work fine if each branch is only worked on by one dev.

Comment: This is a workaround, as you already mentioned that Git does not store any metadata. It just contains pointers to various commits.

Comment: This works great if last modified date is also available in the out put.

Comment: @jon : Try git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' for the date

Answer (score 0):

You can list all of the branches using

```
git branch --all --list
```

But because a branch does not have an owner, I would assume you are asking for the commit that branched off initially. In that case you can use `git log` to find that easily.

```
git log --all --stat --graph --format='%h %d %an %cr %s'
```

This is still manual work if there are a lot of contributors to a branch

Comment: Your "easily" differs from mine :)